# Changing one dto to another

Tags: java, dto

```
@Getter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class GenerateDaByContextDto {
    private String cNumber;
    private BusinessContext businessContext;
    private String zCode;
    private String yCode;
    private String xCode;
    private String event;

    public GenerateContentDto toGenerateContentDto() {
        return GenerateContentDto.builder()
                .businessContext(businessContext)
                .event(event)
                .build();
    }
}
```

I was making code review, when i wondered is it fine to change DTO's like that?
The need was that some methods have `GenerateContentDto` as param and it could be acquired from  `GenerateDaByContextDto` DTO in the code.
Is there another option to make it better? Is it good regarding `SRP` rule?
I have simplified the `DTOs` fields.

Comment: Could you use interfaces instead?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be better place for this question

Comment: @Thomas no i can not, cause it is `DTO` it's data transfering beetween microservices, frontend<->backend and so on. @Karthikeyan Vaithilingam thanks

Comment: Did you look at [mapstruct](https://mapstruct.org/)?

Comment: @SukhpalSingh i don't want to introduce more magic in my project. I want to resolve this simple issue myself. I don't need library for it - really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strongly speaking, it's opinion based and depends on project.

But let's remember [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). DTO's responsible for data holding between layers, not for conversion. I prefer to have a simple converter with method like:

```
public class GenerateDaByContextDtoConverter {
    public GenerateContentDto convert(GenerateDaByContextDto source) {...}
}
```

By the same reason, usually DTOs are immutable. You could use lombok's `@Value` annotation.

The one more solution may be composition, if it consistent with the business logic :

```
class GenerateDaByContextDto {

    private GenerateContentDto generateContentDto;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Does this method need to public and static? You are showing a package method and not static one. In your case I need to create object `GenerateDaByContextDtoConverter`

Comment: If you does not use any frameworks, static one is better. With, for example, Spring Framework, it's singleton bean and the method usually will be public (not static).

Comment: I use `SpringBoot` but why would it better to register bean of `GenerateDaByContextDtoConverter` in container? Why do you think `SpringBoot` need to handle this `lifeCycle` ? Does we really need inversion of control here? Do we need to use framework for that class? I think static could be better even if i use framework. I don' have to be dependend on it in every aspect of my code.

Comment: There is no universal solution. Sometimes 'public static' method is cleaner. But sometimes the conversion logic needs an additional dependencies (for nested DTOs conversion, for example) and in such case IOC is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**You can replace `@Getter` ,`@Builde`r,`@AllArgsConstructo`r,`@NoArgsConstructor` with `@Data`**

this is the better way to do it

```
@Data
public class GenerateDaByContextDto {
    private String cNumber;
    private BusinessContext businessContext;
    private String zCode;
    private String yCode;
    private String xCode;
    private String event;
/*
    public GenerateContentDto toGenerateContentDto() {
        return GenerateContentDto.builder()
                .businessContext(businessContext)
                .event(event)
                .build();
    }
*/
}
```

Comment: what if he doesn't want to allow setters? using `@Data` will also generate this as well, so it is not a better approach for *all cases*

Comment: @Mustahsan , okay , As i know this is the best way to do it ,  If you have an idea please share it because of it will help to me also ,Thanks

Comment: this is a shorthand method if you want to use all of lombok functionalities then it will be concise and better ofcourse, but if you want to use specific and limited annotations then this is not a better way

Comment: you can read about @Data here: https://projectlombok.org/features/Data

Comment: But i need to pass `GenerateContentDto` not `GenerateDaByContextDto` as param to method. I can not easily change other places where methods need this param. The question how to translate beetween this two DTO's. What is the best way?